# Does the reduced column echelon form of a matrix $A$ have the same null space as $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Row reduction never changes the null space of a matrix $A$. But can column reduction change the null space?

I do not think this is true, my attempt at a counterexample is

$$ A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&1&0\\
0&1&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The null space of $A$ equals the span of $[1, 1, -1, -1]$. The column reduced form of $A$ is

$$
R=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the null space of $R$ is the span of $[0,0,c_1, c_2]$ where $c_1, c_2 \in \mathbf{R}$.

So $N(A) \neq N(R)$. But I may have made a mistake as these concepts are still new to me.

As a side note, I suspect that for any invertible matrix, column reduction would *not* change the nullspace, but I'm not sure how to prove this.

Comment: The left null spaces of $A$ and $R$ would be the same though, that the same set of row vectors $\mathbf x^T$ would satisfy both $\mathbf x^T A = \mathbf 0^T$ and $\mathbf x^T R = \mathbf 0^T$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that composition of column operations on $A$ is the same as $A$ right-multiplied with an invertible matrix $T$. e.g.

$$\begin{align*}
A &= \pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1}\\
R &= \underbrace{\pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1}}_A
\underbrace{\pmatrix{1&0&-1&0\\0&1&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}}_T\\
&= \pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}
\end{align*}$$

If $\mathbf v\in N(A)$, i.e. $A\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$, then consider $T^{-1}\mathbf v$,

$$R \left(T^{-1}\mathbf v\right) = ATT^{-1}\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$$

so $T^{-1}\mathbf v \in N(R)$.

And similarly the inverse: if $\mathbf v \notin N(A)$, then $R\left(T^{-1}\mathbf v\right) = ATT^{-1}\mathbf v \ne \mathbf 0$, i.e. $T^{-1}\mathbf v \notin N(R)$.

---

Then your side note about the null space of invertible matrices is obvious:

The null space of an invertible matrix contains only the zero vector $\mathbf 0$, so the null space of the matrix after column operations contains only $T^{-1}\mathbf 0 = \mathbf 0$.

---

For your counterexample, the null space of $A$ has vectors of the form

$$\mathbf v
= \pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\-c_1\\-c_2}
= c_1\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1\\0} + c_2\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\-1}
$$

Then the vectors in $N(R)$ can be computed as:

$$\begin{align*}
T^{-1} &= \pmatrix{1&0&1&0\\0&1&0&1\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1}\\
T^{-1}\mathbf v
&= \pmatrix{c_1-c_1\\c_2-c_2\\-c_1\\-c_2} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\c_1'\\c_2'}\\
&= T^{-1}\left[c_1\pmatrix{1\\0\\-1\\0} + c_2\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\-1}\right]\\
&= c_1\pmatrix{0\\0\\-1\\0} + c_2\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\-1}\\
\end{align*}$$

This shows how $N(R)$ may be derived from $N(A)$ and $T^{-1}$:

$$\begin{align*}
N(A) &= \operatorname{span}([1,0,-1,0],[0,1,0,-1])\\
N(R) &= \operatorname{span}\left(T^{-1}[1,0,-1,0],T^{-1}[0,1,0,-1]\right)
\end{align*}$$

But while the null spaces change, what's preserved here is that a set of independent vectors in $N(A)$, after left-multiplied with $T^{-1}$, will still be a set of independent vectors in $N(R)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very insightful. I overlooked the fact that column operations could also be formulated in a matrix, this approach is much more satisfying.

Answer (score 1):

Column operations can change the nullspace.

Your counterexample is good, except the nullspaces are not quite right. They should be $\text{span}\{[1,0,-1,0], [0,1,0,-1]\}$ and $\text{span}\{[0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]\}$ respectively. (I guess "span of $[0,0,c_1, c_2]$ where $c_1,c_2 \in \mathbb{R}$" is technically fine, although the word "span" could be dropped".)

---

For invertible matrices, check that each column operation does not change the fact that the columns are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you, that all makes sense. I see now that I was describing the format of the vectors themselves so it doesn't make much sense to say span there. A question about your last note: if we specify that the column operations should only be those that bring the matrix closer to reduced column echelon form, then they will never change the dependence relations amongst the columns, right?

Comment: @ZackHelms I think any column operations (regardless of whether or not they move the matrix closer to reduced echelon form) will not change whether or not the columns are linearly independent or linearly dependent. But you should check this yourself.